Is my proposed method for managing cache when required TTL is highly variable reasonable?
I have a service set up as an API with Flask that relies on a couple other rest API's to databases that are relatively slow. I am currently working on a cache system that would release requests sent to my service from relying directly on a query to the other rest API's.
Workflows involving my service would typically not see the database change more than a couple times per day. However, workflows would typically involve a request being sent to my service within a few minutes of database updates occurring. So, I am wondering what the best practice for keeping my TTL low for these situations would be?
My first thought is to set up a listener on the database that will trigger the cache to update in my service whenever and update is made in the database. However, I am not sure if this would be the best practice for this scenario.
